# How can i use React server components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server

i want to try new React api calls server components. I don't find any information about how can i start project with server components. In source code example i find

react-server-dom-webpack/plugin

must i use it? and why we need it in all which use server components? I found it here - https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo/blob/main/scripts/build.js

it doesn't have any documentation on npmjs.

Can i just add .server.jsx prefix to my component and start use them?

Comment: From [What are React Server Components?](https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-react-server-components-work-c8b69595e29f), I found the original demo source: https://github.com/reactjs/server-components-demo. And on that page, the warning, "Server Components are an experimental feature and are not ready for adoption. For now, we recommend experimenting with Server Components via this demo app. Use this in your projects at your own risk."

Comment: I know this is an experimental feature. But they say " this in your projects at your own risk", so how can i try it?

Comment: Follow the instructions on that page? It seems like you want someone to tell you you don't have to follow those instructions.

Comment: I dont found any environment settings instructions, so i asked here

Comment: For example react-fetch package in demo package.json is not exported {fetch} method

Answer (score 0):

The React team highly recommends using a framework like Next.js to kickstart a new React project. (You can find this recommendation in the deep dive section of their documentation [here](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project))

Furthermore, Dan Abramov, one of the core members of the React team, suggests that the most optimal implementation of React Server Components (RSC) can be found in the latest version of Next.js (Next.js 13). You can hear more about his thoughts on this topic in this [episode](https://changelog.com/jsparty/267#t=00:34:12.25) of the JS Party podcast.